# How to animate opacity (or other property) in function in QML file?

Tags: qt, qml

I have created this function in my QML file:

```
function setPanelOpacity(panel, visiblePanel) {
    panel.opacity = (panel === visiblePanel) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This works, but I would like to have the opacity change take 0.5 seconds instead of happening all at once. How can I do that inside this function? (I have seen examples that use states and transitions defined inside a QML object, but nothing that does this entirely within a function like my function here)

**Edit:** I see that I can achieve this (somewhat) by adding a `Behavior` to each of my panel objects, like so:

```
Behavior on opacity {
    NumberAnimation {
        duration: 500
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }
}
```

Having to add this block to all of my objects is a bit of a pain, though. Is there any way to achieve this fully programmatically inside my method, or alternatively to apply this `Behavior` to every object on my page?

Answer (score 0):

QML is designed from the ground up to be a declarative language, and what you have now is the optimal solution. While it will likely be possible to animate using a functions, it will most certainly be less convenient and clean.

If the goal is to avoid code repetition, just implement the desired behavior in your own custom type, then you can instantiate it as much as you want and each instance will have the desired behavior without the need to manually implement it.

Comment: One of my problems is that my (inherited) app has a large number of custom types. I'm trying to find a way of specifying this behavior in one place without re-specifying it inside each of these custom types. Maybe you could take a look at my other question about subclassing `Behavior` and see what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: You are trying to swim against the current, QML is kind of a hit or miss in this regard, it has been designed to be very easy when you use it in the (rather limited) way it was envisioned to be used, and proportionally awkward and off-putting if you try doing with it something its designers did not take into account. It reveals a lot of limitations once you try to use it in "free form", and while some have gotten official workarounds, those are usually very clumsy and just as inflexible. My suggestion from the answer stands, and don't forget, copy and paste is not always all that bad.